# Route Mapping in Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How would I create a route mapping to the following url:

```
http://localhost/SiteName/AdminCP/Topics/EditTopic/28
```

AdminCP is an area -- I can get to the Topics controller and show a list of topics to the user, then the user clicks a link to edit the topic which should
take them to the url above. EditTopic is a controller in AdminCP which returns a single Index action.

This is my AdminCP registration code which is not working.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "AdminCP_default",
            "AdminCP/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller= "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
           "AdminCP_Topics",
           "AdminCP/Topics/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

    }
```

I have been able to reproduce this URL:

```
http://localhost/SiteName/AdminCP/EditTopic/Index/26
```

using this code snippet

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Options", "", "EditTopic", new { id = item.CategoryId }, new { @class = "popup-link" })
```

...but that's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Add before the AdminCP Default Route)

```
context.MapRoute(
            "AdminCP_Topics",
            url: "AdminCP/Topics/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Options","Index","EditTopic", new {id = 1, area = "AdminCP" },null)
```